# Is there way to convert pymssql query to json based on first column values?

Tags: python, json, pymssql

I am trying to convert pymssql query to json where first column "value" will be "key" and corresponding columns will be list of  "key:value".

I have tried using jsondumps but get the "Cursor  is not JSON serializable" error:

```
    `conn = pymssql.connect(server, port, db)
     cursor = conn.cursor('select u_business_service_display_value as Business, name, host_name as hostname, install_status, ip_address, used_for from cmdb_ci_server where u_patching_director_display_value = <Name> AND install_status <> "Retired" AND install_status <> "Pending Retirement" order by Business, hostname')
     for row in cursor:
         print("Business=%s, Name=%s, Hostname=%s, install_status=%s, ip_address=%s, used_for=%s" % (row['Business'], row['name'], row['hostname'], row['install_status'], row['ip_address'], row['used_for']))
     print json.dumps(results, indent=1)
     conn.close()`
```

Output is

```
- Business=AAA, Name=Value, Hostname=vaule, install_status=Retired, ip_address=<ip>, used_for=None
- Business=AAA, Name=Value, Hostname=vaule, install_status=Retired, ip_address=<ip>, used_for=None
- Business=BBB, Name=Value, Hostname=vaule, install_status=Installed, ip_address=<ip>, used_for=Prod
- Business=BBB, Name=Value, Hostname=vaule, install_status=Installed, ip_address=<ip>, used_for=Prod
```

Expected output

````
{
        "AAA":[
        { 
        "Hostname":"Value",
        "install_status":"Retired",
        "ip_address":"<ip>",
        "used_for":"None"
        },
        {
         "Hostname":"Value",
         "install_status":"Retired",
         "ip_address":"<ip>",
         "used_for":"None"
      }
   ],
   "BBB":[ 
      { 
         "Hostname":"Value",
         "install_status":"Installed",
         "ip_address":"<ip>",
         "used_for":"Prod"
      },
      { 
         "Hostname":"Value",
         "install_status":"Installed",
         "ip_address":"<ip>",
         "used_for":"Prod"
      }
   ]
}```
````

Comment: Since you are getting output from iterating through ```cursor``` it's not really clear which code is causing your error. Could you maybe rephrase your question, to make it more readable

Comment: The error is due to this line. " print json.dumps(results, indent=1)".  so asked for a better way to do it. Poojan has given a code piece below but I am facing key error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json
d = defaultdict(list)
for row in cursor:
    values = dict()
    values['name'] = row['name']
    values['hostname'] = row['hostname']
    values['install_status'] = row['install_status']
    values['ip_address'] = row['ip_address'] 
    values['used_for'] = row['used_for]
    d[row['Business']].append(values)

with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(d, fp)
```

- `d` is `defaultdict` with `list` argument so, in case you add key that is not in `d` it will create `list` as value when assigned first time.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks you for quick response. But I am stuck at this error "KeyError: 'AAA'" , I thought it was unicode and die " d[str(row['Business'])].append(values)", did not work.                                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ansible_inventory.py", line 21, in <module>
    d[row['Business']].append(values)
KeyError: u'AAAA'

Comment: Found that "d[row['Business']]" is not setting to any value. Its empty. Hence there is key error. If I use values['Business'] = row['Business] I am able to see the value but from "d[row['Business']]". Strange though.

Comment: Solved this by adding condition                                                                                     def add_element(d, key, values):
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = []
    d[key].append(values)

Comment: @Shashinandan my bad part. I added explanation. I used `defaultdict` but forgot to give `list` argument. I edited answer please read it again. With use of `defaultdict` you are getting rid of that `if condition`. You can run my answer again it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much ! The correction works like charm :)